# Chrome Window.open strugles

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following code:

```
<script>
window.open("https://www.google.com", menubar=0, true);
window.open("https://www.google.com", menubar=0, true);
window.open("https://www.google.com", menubar=0, true);
window.open("https://www.google.com", menubar=0, true);    </script>
```

Injected in a http page.
Chrome opens the link (https://www.google.com) once in a new window (not a new tab, a new window). Why doesn't chrome open it 4 times? I've allowed pop-ups to the modified page. The console says something like:
This page isn't the same-origin, nor the parent page of the url.

What does this mean and how to make it work correctly?

Comment: why are you want to redirect to same page 4 times?? in your case the command (window.open ) will work at first time and it will open the google page. and now it is shifted to a new window it means the parent is changed that's why you are getting the error. and the code u have written may lead to duplication and bug. if u wanted to open same page in 4 windows you have to write separate function for each one

Comment: It's for testing. So i would need to make function a, function b, etc... to open it 4 times?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In java script you can do like this

```
$(function(){ 
    window.open(url, windowName[, windowFeatures]); 
});
```

Comment: would i need to paste this 4 times?

Comment: if you open more than 1 window at a time its a spam.. as per rule you cannot open more than 1 window at a time. here you are forcing browser to do that . that time your browser will block that automatically.

Comment: if you allow pop-up also it wont be possible. its considered as an unwanted activity.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. It's actually a protection mechanism.